# Google Script onEdit function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anyone know if I have to have my google sheet open for the `onEdit()` function to work? I have a background task running that edits the sheet but my function only fires when I manually open the sheet and make an edit real time. Sheets recognizes when my edits are made (both manually and in the background) but my function won't work unless I have it open.

My function pings a url:

```
function onEdit() {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://nosnch.in/tokenhere");
}
```

If sheets won't run the function when the sheet isn't opened is there any way around this?

Comment: Yes. You must have the sheet open for an edit to trigger it.

Comment: Also, you cannot send emails or fetch pages inside the onEdit trigger.

Answer (score 3):

onEdit is a UI triggered function.

You can have the offline background task call `onEdit()` directly as it concludes if it is within the same script

```
function backgroundTask() {
 // do stuff

 onEdit();
}
```

If it is in another script you'll need to call it either as a webapp or library tie-in.